# Is there any way I can play Minecraft: Bedrock Edition) for free on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, minecraft

I have played Minecraft: Bedrock Edition previously but it doesn't free version from now on, also the sonic master have discontinued making free versions so I don't know any new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;dr: No, you can't.

Here's the real answer:

You have two issues:

1. Minecraft Java Edition [can be downloaded for Linux](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download). After you pay for the game, of course. Minecraft Bedrock Edition (a.k.a. Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition) won't work on Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro, for that matter). It is distributed via [the Microsoft/Xbox store](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/games/store/Minecraft-for-Windows/9NBLGGH2JHXJ). Not a downloadable `.exe`. So you can't download that version for Ubuntu. [Some people](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/qemtk8/i_got_minecraft_bedrock_running_with_wine_dxvk_on/) (Reddit link) have gotten it working on Linux. [Here](https://mcpelauncher.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is another one. So it is technically possible, just hard.
2. It isn't free. Neither Minecraft: Java Edition nor Minecraft: Bedrock Edition are free (on Windows, Mac, or Linux). So you have to pay.

If you want an easy way, I'd just create a Windows 10 VM using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or just play Minecraft: Java Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ChristopherHX/linux-packaging-scripts/releases/tag/v0.3.4-688

but you have to have purchased game on google play.

For launch this, you have to make it as executable:

```
chmod +x path/to/file/Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64-v0.3.3.683.AppImage
```

and launch:

```
./path/to/file/Minecraft_Bedrock_Launcher-x86_64-v0.3.3.683.AppImage
```

Now, log-in to your google account and down select pen. There you can choose version.

Now, you can play.

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways to get Minecraft: Java Edition for free, but I don't know if it's legal.
The first way is to download TLauncher (of course Java is required) https://tlauncher.org. Then you need to click

> Run file as program

in the file properties and open the file using Java. Then you can play Minecraft.